# How to detect HTTP UA for a hyperlink from powerpoint

Tags: http, powerpoint, agent

Quick help .. i have a website which is not designed for IE hence i have written php code to read the http ua string to check if it "msie" string exists and redirecting to another page which shows the appropriate message. The trouble with this approach is that when i click the link from MS powepoint 2007 the page redirects to another page though my default browser is Chrome..

I figured that UA is getting set as "mozilla/4.0 (compatible; msie 7.0;" when i click the hyperlink from powerpoint. Is there any other field which can be used to judge that the request is coming from Powerpoint
36 minutes ago · Like

Answer (score 1):

A really annoying bug in PowerPoint. A possible workaround is creating an empty page that contains a meta redirect to the URL you want to redirect to. Just dynamically replace the url you want to redirect to each time you go to this redirect page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Redirecting...</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=**MYREDIRECTURL**" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Redirecting...
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```